# Xamarin iOS ITMS-90022 'Missing required icon file'

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ipa

Xamarin iOS ITMS-90022 'Missing required icon file'

Xamarin - 4.12.3.83
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK - 12.4.0.64
Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11

Attempting to publish .ipa to App Store Connect via Application Loader results in

ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

I have read and tried the tips on this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71397/missing-required-file-icon-error-itms-90022-amp-itms-90023

None of the images contain an alpha channel.

Info.plist

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

Assets.xcassets:

[image]

All images show up in the Asset viewer

ipa contents:

[image]

csproj contains no duplicates/unused images

I have attempted to publish using VS for Mac (2017/2019 as Release/Generic), Microsoft App Center, and Publish from Visual Studio for Windows (Release, iPhone), all result in ITMS-90022.

The lack of detailed information as to why this isn't working is incredibly frustrating.

Edit:

It has worked on VS for Mac (2019) only, not on any other build. Will attempt updating Xamarin.iOS and retrying on App Center, and directly from Visual Studio for Windows (2017) again.

Comment: You have to go into the info.plist and add the path to the 120x120 icon.

Comment: Apple expects all app icons to be represented as an AppIcon.xcasset asset catalog - see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: Worked on VS Mac '19 only... Still nothing will await newer xamarin versions to see if it is fixed.

Comment: Any progress on this?? I am facing the very same situation here

Comment: I have been uploading the package from VS for Mac, still no solution..

Comment: @l_degaray Have same problem happening. Did you managed to resolve it?